# Condensed ElGamal + AES

Tags: aes, diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption

1. In normal ElGamal encryption, the encrypted message is a pair `(gb, gabM)` - that is, the actual "encryption" is simply multiplication by the shared secret `gab`.
2. A common pattern with public-key encryption is to encrypt a symmetric key using PK, and then encode the actual message with the symmetric key.

It seems to me that you could simply use the shared secret `gab` as your symmetric key instead - so your pair would be `(gb, AES(M, gab))`.  (This looks extremely similar to agreeing on an AES key via Diffie-Hellman.)  This would take up less space, putting it on even footing with RSA + AES for a given key-/group-size.

So: has anybody heard of a scheme like this?  If so, does it have a name, and is it actually used?  As for why I'm interested:

**Possible advantage: semantic security without DDH?**

In normal ElGamal, we lose semantic security if we don't have [DDH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie-Hellman_assumption) (given `ga`, `gb` and `c`, we can test whether `c = gab`).  AFAIU, this is because the message is encoded as `E = gabM mod p`, so you can divide by your suspected message (`c = gabM/Mguess`), and test whether it matches `gab`.

It seems to me that if we use `gab` to provide an AES key instead, then recovering a candidate `c` is equivalent to recovering an AES key from a plaintext/ciphertext pair.  I understand that AES is not susceptible to known-plaintext attacks, so does this mean we have semantic security even without DDH?

**Possible advantage: easier generation of private keys?**

With RSA, it takes a reasonable chunk of computational effort to generate a new public/private key pair (because you have to find a probably prime).  With ElGamal, it seems much easier, which means you could rotate your short-term keys much more often, without draining a low-power device.

The more often you rotate your short-term keys, the "better" your forward secrecy is.  (After all, if you rotated your keys so often that each one was only ever used once, then you're basically doing Diffie-Hellman, just re-ordered a bit.)

Comment: You may look at ECIES.

Comment: Perfect!  ECIES/DLIES was pretty much exactly what I was thinking of.  Could you give that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are envisioning has basically been standardized as [the integrated encryption scheme](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) being a hybrid encryption scheme providing message authenticity (IND-CCA security).